# Should we take the site down and set coming soon page while we're working on redesign?

Tags: website-design

Do you guys think that this is a good idea, or you think it may frustrate the user because they don't see the information they are interested in.

I personally don't like this idea, but I want to hear your opinions.

Answer (score 1):

"It depends" is probably the correct answer.

Is the old site inaccurate or misleading? take it down.
Is the old site ok, but just undergoing a redsign, keep it up.

If you provide some more context as to why you are redesigning, the validity of the old site, the timescales, the traffic, the impact on the business of not having a site etc then a more comprehensive answer can be provided

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a coming soon page.

If you create coming soon page then it will not affect your website SEO which was done previously.

If you didn't work on SEO for your old website then you can skip coming soon page design.

also from a user experience perspective, when a visitor visits your website then they will know that something will come. If the user didn't get any info on your website then they assume that there is no more info on this website and they will not return to your website again.